# Why does Xcode says "Cannot find type 'NSPersistentContainer' in scope"?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspersistentcontainer

I just stared making a new Core Data project but without making any changes yet, I am getting this error. Not sure why.

[image]

Comment: Did you `import CoreData`?

Comment: Yes, I did. I am not sure why I see this error.

Comment: Make a clean/remove derived data?

Comment: I am pretty new to this. I just made a fresh project and imported coredata. It shows this error. I made no changes to the AppDelegate

Comment: try clean and build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have named your application "CoreData" thus overwriting the name of the framework `CoreData` so what the compiler is complaining about is that *your* app doesn't have a type `NSPersistentContainer`.

Also, you have a warning on the import statement (`import CoreData`) that hints that something is wrong

Solution: Delete the project and create a new one with a more unique name, even something like `MyCoreDataApp` will do.

Comment: I delete my project and, I create another project with a unique name so it ok and solved .:)
Thank you so much @Joakim